# PHP foreach loop returning extra

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script below that I am hoping would return all the values of a sql table. It does  do this but also returns a number and value after each of the expected lines

```
    $condition = "usernames = '$user'  AND password = '$pass' ";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userbase WHERE $condition")  ;

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)  ;

    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        echo "$k / $v <br>";
        };

    ?>
```

The results look like this

```
      0 / Mick Lathrope 
      name / Mick Lathrope 
      1 / op 
      jobtitle / op 
      2 / 07998 783 989 
      phone / 07998 783 989 
      3 / mwl707 
      usernames / mwl707 
      4 / testpass
      password / testpass
```

All the data is there that i need But why am I also getting a number list ?

Any help please ?

Comment: Besides moving to MySQLi or PDO, look at the second argument for MySQL_fetch_array() and in particular the default value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ;
```

to index only by column name

Answer (score 0):

because you have used [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

If you want only columns then use [mysql-fetch-assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 0):

1. drop `mysql_*` for PDO or mysqli;
2. you want to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get just keys and no number indexes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) you have to specify the result type you want, otherwise you get both:
 `MYSQL_ASSOC` or `MYSQL_NUM`,

Example:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){...}
```